# Laravel 5.3 RESTFul API without authentication

Tags: api, laravel, authentication, restful-architecture

I want to create an API with Laravel 5.3 but i don't need any kind of authentication. Is it possible to get rid of it? I don't want any token or any kind of authentication.

Comment: Yup it's possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To help anyone in my situation who arrive here : be aware that any route in api.php is prefixed by "api/". 
It is set in `/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`.

So :

`Route::get('/delegates', "APIController@delegate");`

Will be accessible from

`http://www.yourdomain.com/api/delegates`

Sorry if it's a bit off-topic, but hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible
normally in your

> route/api.php

you'd have something like

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});
```

you just need to remove the part of the middleware that's referencing auth.
So the above would look like:

```
Route::middleware('api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
  return $request->user();
  //middleware('api') URI prefix. which would become '/api/user'
});
```

or

```
Route::apiResource('user', 'UserController');
//same as above but includes crud methods excluding 'create and edit'
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can get rid of it. Just setup your routes to don't use any middleware.

Create your API routes on `routes/api.php` file, then modify the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file to set your middlewares correctly:

Remove (or add) the middlewares you don't want on `api` middleware group.

By default, L5.3 comes with two middlewares on `api` group:

```
'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
```

The first one provides a rate limiting to your API (60 requests/minute),
the second substitutes your model bindings.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, just create route to your controller and return data (Without any auth middleware).

Answer (score -1):

Allow your route to run without auth

```
Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if (!$request->is('api/*'))
  {
    return parent::handle($request, $next);
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

Set route like this

```
'api' => 'APIController'
```

This is method in APIController ('/api/data')

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{
  return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: VerifyCsrfToken middleware isn't the guy that Authenticates users. Your answer does not solve the Authentication problem.